# Testing for sensitivity and specificity: how to summarise TP, FP, FN, and TN using R, dplyr/tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

I am testing the diagnostic values of the new methodology and would like to test the sensitivity and specificity of this method.
Let's say, that we have a dataset of 200 patients and controls, with the test results varying from 1 to 8.

```
set.seed(123)    
Df<-
    data.frame(id=1:200,
      group = sample(c("Patient", "Control"), 200, TRUE),
      test = sample(5, 200, TRUE))
```

I have grouped "respondents" depending on the group variable and test result as follows:

```
Df%>%
    group_by(group, test) %>% 
      summarise(Num=n()) %>% 
      spread(group, Num)%>%
      mutate(reference=test)
```

How could I summarise the number of true positives, false positives, false negatives and false positives in respective columns, using respective test result as a threshold?
I suspect that the mutation should start like that (if using case_when):

```
mutate(TP=case_when(id.group=="Patient"&test>=reference~[..summarize conditional cells...], FP=case_when id.group=="Control"&test>=reference~[..summarize conditional cells...]), etc.
```

but cannot realize how can I summarise conditional cells.
Could you please help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what exactly would your desired out put be? (When using random data, please use `set.seed()` so we can get the same random values as you for testing)

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Have added now.

Comment: What is the formula to calculate TP, FP, FN, and TN? Can you show first few rows of your expected output?

Comment: I would like to summarise the number of values as variables. Let's say, I want to know how many are true positives for the reference value of 1 and higher. So, the condition is group=="Patient"&test>=reference. And the TP value for the reference row "1" should  contain the sum of "Patients" who had the test equal or higher than 1.

Comment: for the reference value of "2", the columns should be as follows: TP=80, FP=99, FN=12, TN=9. For the reference value of "3" - as follows: TP=67, FP=77, FN=32, TN=24, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,

```r
mutate(TP=rev(cumsum(Patient)),
       FP=rev(sum(Patient)-cumsum(Patient)),
       TN=rev(cumsum(Control)),
       FN=rev(sum(Control)-cumsum(Control))) %>%
  select(reference, TP, FP, TN, FN)
```